# How to GrayScale an image in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to use image filters in CodeIgniter PHP, I want to convert user input image in grayscale image, I am trying this in PHP CodeIgniter framework, 
It is not converting the image to grayscale, nothing is displaying.

Here is my code for controller:

```
public function grayscale(){
    $data['title'] ='Grayscale Image';
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/grayscale';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width'] = '2000';
    $config['max_height'] = '2000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $realImages = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
        $data['img2']=imagefilter($realImages, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);       
        print $this->load->view('pages/result',$data,true);
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
<form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' name="userfile" size="20" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

Result view:

```
<div class="invert-grid-item Result">
<img src="<?php echo $img2;?>">            
</div>
```

Comment: imagecreatefrompng(http://localhost/ImageTools//assets/images/crop/download20.png) you have double / in filename, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I don't know, whats the problem exactly?

Comment: try change $img_path = base_url().'/assets/images/crop/'.$this->upload->data('file_name');  to $img_path = base_url().'assets/images/crop/'.$this->upload->data('file_name');

Comment: getting same error

Comment: can you check if this file exists in crop directory?

Comment: crop directory means?

Comment: ImageTools/assets/images/crop this directory

Comment: yes it does exists, I have updated my code please check, the error is gone but nothing is happening now

Comment: @Rainmx93 can you help?

Comment: ok, one more thing show us your pages/result view file

Comment: I have edited the result view in post.

Comment: imagefilter() function returns true on success and false on failure, so in your view <img src="<?php echo $img2;?>">  $img2 contains only true or false. I think you need to save that image first and then return image path to your view

Comment: how can you please tell me? how to echo the grayscaled image?
Is there anyother way to convert image to grayscale in codeigniter php only except using imagefilter()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, if you wan't to save image in another dir just change `$config['upload_path'].'/'.` to another path

```
    public function grayscale(){
    $data['title'] ='Grayscale Image';
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/grayscale';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width'] = '2000';
    $config['max_height'] = '2000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $realImages = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

        $data['img2']=$config['upload_path'].'/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];

        imagefilter($realImages, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);       
        imagepng($realImages, $data['img2']);

        print $this->load->view('pages/result',$data,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to check that image is png or jpg?

Comment: `if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] == IMAGETYPE_PNG){} else if ($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG){}`

Comment: you can read more about php function exif_imagetype() http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Comment: I'm curious... Why don't you just do this with css?

Comment: @Alex because the task is to do in php codeigniter.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to waste server power doing this. Either save it as grayscale initially or do it with css would be my thinking.

Comment: @Alex please guide me in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274893/how-to-download-an-uploaded-image-in-codeigniter-php